# Считать из файла до символа

Tags: c++, файлы

У меня в файле есть специальный символ "&", который делит его на две части для считывания. (Таблица и данные). Как при этом можно ограничить чтение до этого символа, и потом начать чтение с этого же символа (не учитывая его, конечно) в другую переменную?

Я так понимаю, мне нужен `while ()`. Табличку я считываю следующим образом

```
   while (std::getline(input, key, '#') && std::getline(input, value)) { ...}
```

перед этим мне нужно еще одно условие.

Пример файла

```
00#a
11#b
&
abcabca
```

Comment: Я бы разбор строки на ключ-значение по # отделил от собственно чтения строки, тогда и проблема улетучится.

Answer (score 2):

Да все очень просто (права подозреваю, что опять сломается:) )

```
std::string key, value;
while (input.peek() != '&' && std::getline(input, key, '#') && std::getline(input, value))
{
    std::cout << key << "=" << value << "\n";
}
// читаем остаток
std::string line;
std::getline(input, line); // прочитаем амерсанд, что бы не мешался дальше
while (std::getline(input, line)) {
    std::cout << ">> " << line << '\n';
}
```

`input.peek()` - это такая функция, которая подглядывает следующий символ, доступный для чтения.

Comment: Спасибо! а как остаток вообще "понимает", что нужно читать после "&"?

Comment: там есть peek - он остановит первый цикл, как только первый символ в строке будет равен `&`. Следующий цикл начнет читать с этого места. Правда второй цикл все таки прочитает этот &, но дополнительный `
    std::getline(input, line);` перед вторым циклом прочитает строку с амперсандом.

Comment: Никак, он же & тоже читает)

Comment: можно ли его пропустить?

Comment: поправил код, там теперь "пустое чтение"

Comment: @KoVadim,  а нельзя си вторую часть считывать посимвольно? И к дополнению, про игнорирование "&" -- можно применить input.ignore(1)

Comment: ""&" -- можно применить input.ignore(1)" - нет, нельзя. будет проигнорирован один символ, а перевод строки останется...   "а нельзя си вторую часть считывать посимвольно?" а кто мешает? `char c; while(input.get(c)) { делаем что то с c; }`

Answer (score 1):

Можно по простому, как то так например:

```
ifstream File_read;
File_read.open(my_path, ios::in); 

vector<string>Result_data_vector_1; //Сюда записываем считанные строки из файла до &
 vector<string>Result_data_vector_2; //Сюда записываем считанные строки из файла после &

string Line_string;
int status=0;

    while (!File_read.eof())
    {
        getline(File_read, Line_string);

        if(Line_string == "&")
        {
            status=1;
        }
        else
        {
  if(status==0)
    {
        Result_data_vector_1.push_back(Line_string);
    }
    else
    {
        Result_data_vector_2.push_back(Line_string);
    }
      }
```

}

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113512/discussion-on-answer-by-optimus1-----).

Comment: ну вот зачем перемещать в чат. ну его там будет читать.